# How to theme dialog for API 10 to API 17?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme

I'm trying to change whole theme of my dialog.

Here is style for my dialog:

```
<style name="DialogWindowTitleText">
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/PRIORITY_HIGH</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomDialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DialogWindowTitleText</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomDialogWindowTitle</item>

    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DialogWindowTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Inverse</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@color/blue</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_dark_disable_only</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_light_disable_only</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryNoDisable">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryNoDisable">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverseNoDisable">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHintInverse">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Here is code that I use to create dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.CustomDialog));
    builder.setTitle(this.getTitleText());
    builder.setItems(itemsID, this);
    builder.show();
```

Nothing changes in both API 10 and API 17.

Answer (score 2):

You could use library StyledDialogs, which makes styling of dialogs super easy. You will get same look on API level 10 and 17:

https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Comment: Is there any solution that doesn't require 3rd party libraries?

Comment: I'm not aware about such solution. Why can't you use our library? It's open-source under business-friendly Apache License.